# A uniform version of Bashmakov's theorem for elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, galois-representations

Let $E/\mathbb Q$ be an elliptic curve. Serre's open image theorem is the statement that the image of the Galois group $G_{\mathbb Q}$ into $GL_2(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$ by it's action on the torsion points has an index that's bounded by a constant as $n\to\infty$ (and in fact the index is $1$ for most prime powers).

Let us now fix a generator $g \in E(\mathbb Q)$. Then, $G_\mathbb Q$ injects into $GL_2(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)\ltimes (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^2$ by it's action on the $n$ roots of $g$ and torsion points and Bashmakov's theorem (at least the version I know in Lang's Elliptic Curves, Diophantine approximation) guarantees us that  the index is $1$ for almost all prime powers. Is there a uniform version of Bashmakov's theorem in the literature?